# Horizontal key with inverted ordering

Tags: gnuplot

When displaying the `key` using `gnuplot 4.6`, one can invert the ordering of the items in the key using `set key invert`

See, e.g.

```
set key invert
plot x, -x
```

The label for `-x` will be the top one.

Now, if use a horizontal key, e.g.

```
set key horizontal invert
plot x, -x
```

The key for `x` will be the leftmost legend, despite `invert` being set or not.

How can I invert the ordering of the keys in a horizontal legend?

Note: I know I can invert the ordering in the `plot` command, but that is not the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This combination of `horizontal` and `invert` is not supported, you may want to submit a feature request to add this.

Depending on your real use case, you could misuse the `width` option:

```
set key horizontal width -19
```

You may need to adapt the `width` settings depending on the font and terminal. And for very different title lenghts this does not look good.

As an example consider the script

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo size 800,500
set output 'keyinvert.png'
set multiplot layout 1,2
set key invert
plot x, -x, x**2

set key horizontal noinvert width -19
replot
unset multiplot
```

which gives the result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising for my case. I'll give other people some time to come up with nice answers before accepting your answer. I will file the feature request.

Comment: @Bernhard Great, thanks for reporting the feature request. I played around a bit with `set key horizontal`. I think the result of a potential `set key horizontal invert` would be equivalent to my proposed answer, because each horizontal key entry has the same width, which is set by the longest entry. Maybe this might be considered a bug, we'll see `:)`

Comment: The help suggests that invert makes invert ordering bottom-up, which is of course not meaningful for horizontal orientation.